# Выравнивание картинки по горизонтали

Tags: html, css

Как выровнять картинки по горизонтали? Чтоб шло одно за другим?

```
<div style="width: 20%; float: left; text-align: left; padding: 1.5cm 0 0 ">
<:#cart_pay_receiver_director_title^html/>:<br/><:#cart_pay_receiver_accounter_title^html/>:
</div>
<div style="width: 40%; float: left; text-align: center">
</div>
<img src="/attach/chekushkinia.gif">
<img src="/attach/stamp.gif">
</div>
<div style="width: 20%; float: left; padding: 1.5cm 0 0 0">
</div>
(<:#cart_pay_receiver_director_name^html/>)<br />(<:#cart_pay_receiver_accounter_name^html/>)
</div>
т.е. чтоб все было в одну строчку. как это сделать?
```

Comment: повыводите все стили в цсс классы, сами же потом будете мучаться

Comment: Ответ на самом деле не такой. Нужно было сгруппировать дивы и выровнять их.

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно почитать [эту статью](http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/pozitsionirovanie/inline-block-simple-property-for-complex-tasks.html), с помощью этого совета можно выстраивать в ряд элементы, которые будут подстраиваться под размеры друг друга и не "подлазить" один под один в случае использования float:left.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, лишние закрывающие /див после изображений и в конце, перенос тега бр/, во-вторых, что бы всё было в одну строчку - добавьте к этому быдлокоду в каждый див ещё параметр "display: inline;", и к картинкам тоже.

Answer (score 1):

Засунуть все в таблицу или у родительского элемента прописать `style='white-space:nowrap'`. Если вы допускаете возможность переноса, то хватит и `float:left`.

Comment: Имхо, плохая идея верстать таблицами.

Comment: Про блочно-табличную верстку слышали?

Comment: Разумеется слышал, но всё, что можно заверстать блоками - лучше верстать блоками.

Comment: То, что выглядит как таблица, надо верстать таблицей. Фанаты дивов меня с ума сводят, когда гордо показывают код <pre><div class="td">text</div><div class="td">text</div><div class="td">text</div></pre> и 15кб css, чтобы это работало как надо.

Comment: @Sh4dow, полностью с вами согласен! Но и совать таблицы куда ни попадя - тоже плохо.